# Hadoop SequenceFile - auto increment key for records

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2, sequencefile

I'm thinking to use a SequenceFile as "a little database" to store small files. I need that concurrency-client could store small file in this SequenceFile and retrieve an unique id (key of the record).

Is it possibile ? I'm new to hadoop and I'm reading a lot but I can't figure if it's possibile or not.

If yes, please post a small example (or some reference) if not. What can I do with hadoop for my necessity ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in the end it's not possible to do what I wanted.

So I switched to [HBase](https://hadoop.apache.org/) and I'm storing files as rows in a table.

Now the performance are ok and all seems to go in the right way.